# Как сделать копию наследника по указателю C++

Tags: c++, ооп, c++11, c++14

Есть ряд классов: `Shape` - родитель (абстрактный),  его наследуют `CompositeShape`, `Rectangle`, `Circle` и т. д.. В `CompositeShape` передаётся  `Shape *shape`, необходимо клонировать сущность,  на которую указывает `*shape`. Как это можно сделать?
shape.hpp

```
class Shape
{
public:
  virtual void move(const point_t &posTo);
  virtual void move(const double dx, const double dy);
  virtual double getArea() const = 0;
  virtual rectangle_t getFrameRect() const = 0;
  point_t getPosition() const;
  virtual void print(std::string name) const;
  virtual void scale(const double coefficient) = 0;
protected:
  Shape(const point_t pos);
  point_t position_;
};
```

shape.cpp

```
Shape::Shape(const point_t pos) :
position_(pos)
{
}
void Shape::move(const point_t &posTo)
{
  position_ = posTo;
}

void Shape::move(const double dx, const double dy)
{
  position_.x += dx;
  position_.y += dy;
}
point_t Shape::getPosition() const
{
  return position_;
}
void Shape::print(const std::string name) const
{
  std::cout << name << std::endl;
  std::cout << "center = (" << position_.x << ", " << position_.y << ")" << 
  std::endl;
}
```

И функция CompositeShape, в котором возникает проблема

```
void CompositeShape::addComponent(Shape *shape)
{
  if (shape == nullptr) {
    std::cout << "Exception: can add null element" << std::endl;
}

if (length_ < maxlength_) {

   auto shape1 = &(shape);
   Shape *shape2 = *shape1; 
   shapes_[length_] = shape2;
   length_++;
  setPosition();

} else {
   Shape **shapes1 = shapes_;
   shapes_ = new Shape *[maxlength_ + 5];
   for (int i = 0; i < maxlength_; i++) {
   shapes_[i] = shapes1[i];
  }
   delete[] shapes1;
   maxlength_ += 5;
   addComponent(shape);
 }
}
```

Сам класс Composite наследует Shape. При этом идея использовать auto

```
 auto shape1 = &(shape);
 Shape *shape2 = *shape1;
```

не дала нужного результата, т.к. фактически указатель ссылался на ту же сущность (объект), что и передаваемый, а хочется, чтобы создалась новая сущность, на которую указывает shape2, но на нее не указывает входной указатель. При этом dynamic_cast не вариант, т.к. количество фигур (классов наследников Shape) может увеличится.

Comment: Сделать виртуальную функцию clone в базовом классе.

Comment: И поправив заголовок добавить в вопрос собственного кода.

Answer (score 2):

Для лучшего понимания - в [коде](http://ideone.com/4Yswxy):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Abstract
{
public:
    virtual void me() = 0;
    virtual Abstract * Clone() = 0;
    virtual ~Abstract(){}
};

class Base: public Abstract
{
public:
    void me()
    {
        cout << "Base\n";
    }
    Abstract * Clone()
    {
        return new Base;
    }
    virtual ~Base(){}
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    void me()
    {
        cout << "Derived\n";
    }
    Derived * Clone()
    {
        return new Derived;
    }
    virtual ~Derived(){}
};

void who(Abstract * a)
{
    Abstract * b = a->Clone();
    b->me();
    delete b;
};

int main()
{
    Base    * b = new Base;
    Derived * d = new Derived;

    who(b);
    who(d);

    delete b;
    delete d;

}
```

Comment: а деструкторы в main кто будет вызывать? И функция Clone  в производных классах может иметь тип своего класса.

Comment: @KoVadim не может ведь, сигнатуры разные будут

Comment: @int3 может, может:)

Comment: @KoVadim Ну, это всего лишь пример :) Но... пожалуй, да. Показываю, что можно вернуть и тот же тип - в классе Base, и производный - в Derived. Теперь устраивает?

Comment: @int3: Во-первых, тип возвращаемого значения функции не является частью ее сигнатуры. Во-вторых, ковариантные типы возвращаемого значения -  хорошо известное свойство языка..

Comment: @AnT, KoVadim, интересно, не знал. Спасибо.

Answer (score -1):

Предложенный выше ответ позволит вам клонировать производные классы, если метод Clone сделать виртуальным!

```
Base    * b = new Base;
Derived * d = b;
who(d);
```

Я бы порекомендовал попробовать использовать конструктор переноса, если объект, с которого клонировали в дальнейшем не нужен.